# Reading browser's POST request content to Java

Tags: java, html, textbox, character-encoding

in my web page, there is a form that sends via POST request data to my web server. In my server (Java) i'm reading the request's content, but some characters are not being read well. For example, "=" turns into "%3D", ":" turns into "%3A" and " " turns into "+". How can I make my web server read these characters as they were written in the text box?

Thanks, Tomer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are the URL encoded versions of the characters.

If you are in a Servlet context and you simply do request.getParameter() you should automatically get the decoded (normal) versions.

If for some reason you aren't getting those, you can use `java.net.URLDecoder.decode(input, "UTF-8");` to decode manually, but you might wanna do some root cause analysis to see why you are getting encoded stuff in the first place. Maybe your web form is doing double encoding?

Comment: Your second advice works, but let see if we can save the decoding process, by changing the HTML encoding. This is the code of my web form: <form method="post" action="http://127.0.0.1:10000/chat_service/send_message"> -- (no encoding tag in the HTML page)
<textarea id="send_text_box" name="param1" cols="40" rows="2"></textarea></br></br></br></br></br>
<input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>